# Visual Studio 201x project settings

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution with many (>20) projects.
When I change "Property Manager | Microsoft.Cpp.Win32.user" settings, it applies to ALL projects. This is good when I need to set the Include/Library directories.

However, I found out that this setting is shared across my Visual Studio 2010 & Visual Studio 2013.
I was hoping to do legacy stuff (using old boost library, old Microsoft SDK, etc) in Visual Studio 2010... and new boost/MS-SDK stuff in Visual Studio 2013.

Does anyone know how to segregate the Include/Library directories settings in a better fashion? (without painstakingly setting up individual projects' include/lib folders.)

Comment: It is worse than that, it will also change settings across all solutions and across all VS versions that use the same MSBuild version number.  If that is not suitable then you'll have to create your own project property sheet of course.  And stake that pain, just the normal busywork of configuring a project.  You can create your own project template with File > Export Template so the active property sheets are preset.

Comment: See [Working with Project Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/669zx6zc.aspx), in particular the section titled *Sharing reusable property configurations*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't run into this case yet, but could tomorrow.  The only quick fix I can think of is to set up virtual machines for CaseA/CaseB. But I realize that isn't an elegant solution.  If I find something better I'll post here.